# how to delete vSphere files with PowerCLI?

Tags: powercli

RVTools outputs a vHealth report that lists "zombie" (orphaned) files and shows them in the format [DatastoreName] VMfolder/virtualDiskName.vmdk. I can go to the GUI and delete the file and it's fine. I've been doing that for years. But, I want to figure out a command that can take input like that and delete the file so that I can do them all quickly as I have probably 100 to do. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I tried looking into Get-VDisk and Remove-VDisk, but those don't seem to be the right commands. I can't even figure out what input Get-VDisk is looking for.

```
Get-VDisk -Name 'MyDisk' -Datastore $ds
```

What is "MyDisk"!? There is nothing more than that to explain it in their documentation.

Also, notably, I am using connect-viserver with a connection to vCenter Server; so, I assume that will work somehow. If I have to specify a particular ESXi server, then I would have to do much more work to figure out which one to point to.

edit: I tried Get-HardDisk and Remove-HardDisk which almost worked, but then it said, "The requested operation is only supported for devices attached to VM." And of course, the point is that it is not attached to a VM. So, next.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `New-PSDrive` to drive to map a VMFS datastore, like so

```
New-PSDrive -Name TgtDS -Location (Get-Datastore MyVolName) -PSProvider VimDatastore -Root '/'
```

Then to delete /vmfs/volumes/MyVolName/myFolder/myfile.ext

```
del TgtDS:\myFolder\myfile.ext
```

I'm not familiar with `Get-VDisk` and also not finding much documentation. Parent topic [here](https://vdc-repo.vmware.com/vmwb-repository/dcr-public/847b8d79-9752-43d3-8217-8270ab647679/1e992a3d-ac47-4453-8182-457145215c40/GUID-B0C153CA-0C24-452C-A9D5-37CC92AA0707.html) suggests it's SPBM related.

**Edit:** Another approach, following [Get-ChildItem returns wrong path on VMware datastore](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72965486/). On orphaned .vmdk results of

```
Get-ChildItem -Path vmstores:\vCenterHostName.domain.tld@443\DCName\DatastoreName\Folder
```

`Remove-Item` has removed the files from my datastore, despite this exception: "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object." Neither approach would be suitable for mounted .vmdk. Removing orphaned ones has not caused problems in my environment.

Comment: Uh oh, it looks like this does sort of work, but it is not the same as deleting the file from the vSphere client. In fact, it leaves -flat.vmdk, -ctk.vmdk -delta.vmdk files behind. At first, I thought this was fine because I can use this method to delete those files too. But when i did that, it looks like it corrupted the virtual machine. The edit settings page now shows a bunch of junk text. So, this is NOT a good idea until we understand better how to do this!

Comment: Updated the example for deletion of files in a general way, to avoid implying that deleting vmdk this way is generally safe

Comment: Maybe it didn't corrupt the VM? I restarted my web browser and restarted the VM and now it looks fine. ??? Too much weirdness though. VMware needs to create proper support for this, or better yet rearchitect to avoid the possibility of this problem in the first place. Thanks for the help!