# Get-ChildItem returns wrong path on VMware datastore

Tags: powershell, datastore, powercli, get-childitem, vcenter

I am using Get-ChildItem on a vCenter datastore to find an ISO, however the FullName attribute (also PSPath and PSParentPath, but not FolderPath or DatastoreFullPath) repeats itself:

My command:

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse -Path vmstores:/IP@443/vCenter/DATASTORE/vCloud01/media/c7129498-3290-4a7e-a7e1-5c80499e729f -include *.iso | select FullName
```

My output:

> FullName : vmstores:/IP@443/vCenter/DATASTORE/vCloud01/media/c7129498-3290-4a7e-a7e1-5c80499e729f/vCloud01/media/c7129498-3290-4a7e-a7e1-5c80499e729f/de6f4133-e6fc-4377-9da9-de53a945b1b4/media-7b3cd83b-8b37-4a50-9ed3-9ae9f4d6e87a.iso

What I am expecting:

> FullName : vmstores:/IP@443/vCenter/DATASTORE/vCloud01/media/c7129498-3290-4a7e-a7e1-5c80499e729f/de6f4133-e6fc-4377-9da9-de53a945b1b4/media-7b3cd83b-8b37-4a50-9ed3-9ae9f4d6e87a.iso

Am I using this wrong? Is this the expected output? Should I be using a different cmdlet instead? Worst case scenario, I can probably fix the path with some regex/string replacement.

Comment: As aside, `-Filter '*.iso'` would be much faster than `-Include '*.iso'`

Comment: I'm not recreating that behavior in v11.5